# How to access EC2 instance in different region from lambda in another region

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

In the same account, I have lambda in us-east-2 and EC2 instance in us-east-1. I want to connect to the EC2 instance either by ssh or having a api server running in EC2 from the lambda.

How can i Achieve this

Comment: I would not recommend accessing an EC2 instance using SSH from a Lambda. Is the EC2 instance publicly accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can just enable the SSM agent on a target ec2 instance and attach a Systems manager Instance core Instance profile to target machine and create a lambda in source region where you want to run commands.
Here is the sample lambda code below`import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
# Specify the EC2 instance ID and the target region
instance_id = 'your-instance-id'
target_region = 'us-west-2'  # Replace with your desired region

```
# Initialize the SSM client in the target region
ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm', region_name=target_region)

# Specify the SSM command to run on the EC2 instance
ssm_command = 'ls -la /'

try:
    # Execute the SSM command on the EC2 instance
    response = ssm_client.send_command(
        InstanceIds=[instance_id],
        DocumentName='AWS-RunShellScript',
        Parameters={'commands': [ssm_command]}
    )

    command_id = response['Command']['CommandId']
    print(f"SSM command sent to EC2 instance. Command ID: {command_id}")

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': f"SSM command sent to EC2 instance. Command ID: {command_id}"
    }

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error sending SSM command: {e}")
    return {
        'statusCode': 500,
        'body': f"Error sending SSM command: {e}"
    }
```

`